# using a variable to define position in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing out some code for making names float around randomly.  My general question is how do we apply variables to style attributes?  My specific example is as follows.  First I tried this:

```
<body>
Is this it?
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div id="floatName" style="left:50px; top:150px">James</div>
<div id="n2">Sarah</div>

<script>$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( "#floatName" ).animate({
    left: "100px",
    top: "200px"
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  $( "#2" ).animate({
    left: "300px",
    top: "20px"
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>

</body>
```

This works as I expected. Next I wanted to randomize the animation to that the left and top change.  However, I don't know how to do this. One try looks like this:

```
  $( "#floatName" ).animate({
    x = Math.random()*500
    y = Math.random()*500
    left: x + "px",
    top: y + "px"
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Obviously didn't work and I'm having problems finding the solution.

Comment: Didn't look at your code too closely, but you can't define the variables in an object like that.  You could call functions and perform calculations inline:  `left: Math.random()*500 + 'px', …`

Comment: Ok, I found some syntax errors.   I see that I need to use var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*500,  -> I need to declare x and y as variables and end lines with commas.  But I don't think that doesn't answer my underlying question though.

Comment: How does it not answer?

Comment: It did, thanks. I was writing my comment as you were posting yours.

Comment: If you need to do something with details, refer to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/.  As part of the method, there is a *step* function, which might enable you to recalculate values in between animation phases

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/veqne72f/

```
 $( "#floatName" ).animate({
   left: Math.random()*500 + "px",
    top: Math.random()*500 + "px"
  }, 500, function() {
   // Animation complete.
 });
```